# Button not working in layout

Tags: java, android

Am new to Android so just practising on small stuff, what am trying to do is a button(B1) in the (mainactivity) layout and when I click it , it changes to another layout(main) which has another button (B2)which changes back to mainactivity layout out on-click , B1 is working okey , but B2 not working any ideas?

```
package com.example.android;

import java.util.Random;
import java.awt.*;
import com.example.android.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button btn;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clickme);  
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(R.layout.main);          
            /*Random rand = new Random();
            btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, rand.nextInt(255),
                    rand.nextInt(255), rand.nextInt(255)));*/


            }
});
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

this is (main) layout

```
package com.example.android;

import com.example.android.R;
import java.util.Random;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main extends Activity {

    Button btn;
    TextView text;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ChangeColor);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                /*Random rand = new Random();
                btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, rand.nextInt(255),
                        rand.nextInt(255), rand.nextInt(255)));
                text.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, rand.nextInt(255),
                        rand.nextInt(255), rand.nextInt(255)));*/
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: you're not navigating from MainActivity to Main where you acctually handeled the click event of button B2

Comment: In MainActivity use `Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main.Class);  
            startActivity(intent); `  and in Main on button click use  `finish();`

Comment: i tried the intent , but whben i click , the program crashes "unfortunatly Android has stopped"

Comment: When createing the intent do `Intent intent = new Intent();` then `intent.setClass(Main.Class);` then call `startActivity(intent);`

Comment: Have you added your Main activity in manifest file. If not, try to add you activity in manifest file and then try to follow "Raghunandan" comment.

Comment: When you change `layout` by calling `setContentView` it doesn't change the activity (Main (or other) activity is never called) so you just have new ui components loaded, but no click handler is assigned to the button B2 in the new layout.

Comment: @fadytaher did you solve your issue, let us know so you we can further help you thanks

Answer (score 1):

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` is not doing what you think.

To naviguate to activities you have to use `intents` like the others sugested in the comments

First decalre your context:

```
final Context context = this;
```

then pass it to your intent:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
       Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class); 
       startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Comment: do you mean MainActivity.class? Because MainActivity.Class just gives me a syntax error

Comment: yes you are right, I made an edit